# TypeError: isfile() missing 1 required positional argument : 'remotepath'

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

```
with pysftp.Connection(ipaddr, username="uname", password="pass", cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.put(uploc + ufile, "/home/pi/PIFTP/dloads/" + ufile)
    checkfile = ("/home/pi/PIFTP/dloads/" + ufile)
    chfile = pysftp.Connection.isfile(checkfile)
    if chfile == True:
        print (Style.BRIGHT + "[" + Fore.GREEN + "OK" + Fore.WHITE + "] ")
    else:
        print (Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + ipaddr + " is unacsessible")
```

As you can see I'm trying to check a file that is just uploaded. In this case `"/home/pi/PIFTP/dloads/" + ufile` is file's remote download path. What am I missing? Thanks.

Also file arrives before error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `Connection` instance `sftp` you have, not the class.

```
chfile = sftp.isfile(checkfile)
```

Comment: ouf. I feel dumb now. Thanks :)